# How to pass array using spread syntax into method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I am trying to pass an array into a method but having issues with quotes. Here is a case similar to what I am trying to achieve.

```
const remove = ['blue', 'round', 'tall']

function removeClass(param) {
    foo.classList.remove(param)
}  

removeClass(...remove)
```

The issue is that the result is `foo.classList.remove('blue, round, tall')` which won't work. I am trying to achieve this `foo.classList.remove('blue', 'round', 'tall')`

I have tried using `` remove.map(el => `'${el}'`).join(',') `` but then the result is `foo.classList.remove("'blue', 'round', 'tall'")` which also doesn't work.

Comment: Your `removeClass` function is designed to only remove one class. You'd need to define a rest parameter or the `arguments` object to get them all. All depends on how you want to design your function.

Comment: Or just don't hide behind a function: `foo.classList.remove(...remove)`

Answer (score 3):

Try using rest parameters:

```
const remove = ['blue', 'round', 'tall'];

function removeClass(...param) {
    foo.classList.remove(...param);
}  

removeClass(...remove);
```